# Terminating code as std::bad_function_call when running the dpcpp code

Tags: c++, intel, dpc++

When i try to run a vector addition dpcpp program. It  throws the error as

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_function_call'
  what():  bad_function_call
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Below is the sample code :
`

```
#include<CL/sycl.hpp>
#include<iostream>
#include<chrono>
using namespace sycl;
int main()
{
    constexpr int N=10;
    int i;
    std::array<int,N> a;
    std::array<int,N> b;
    std::array<int, N> c;
    auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        a[i]=i;
        b[i]=N-i;
    }
    buffer a_buffer(a);
    buffer b_buffer(b);
    buffer c_buffer(c);
    queue q;
    q.submit([&] (handler &h){
        accessor acc_a(a_buffer,h);
        accessor acc_b(b_buffer,h);
        accessor acc_c(c_buffer,h);
        q.parallel_for(N ,[=](id<1> i) {
            
        });
        });
    q.wait();
     auto stop = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        auto duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(stop-start);
        std::cout<<duration.count();
    host_accessor h_a(c_buffer ,read_only);
    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
    std::cout<<c[i]<<std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

`

Please help me to resolve this issue. Thanks in advance.

I tried to run a program but it throws an error

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add (consistent!) indentation to your code, to make it possible to read and understand your code. Also please add a few empty lines to add paragraphs,

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you already created a handler `h` for the queue, just change this line

> q.parallel_for(N ,[=](id<1> i)

to

> h.parallel_for(N ,[=](id<1> i)